# calculating distance between two distributions from samples of different size

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, machine-learning, gaussian

I'm looking for some general guidance on where to look if I want to solve this problem I encountered:

I have two unknown distributions- p and q, from the same family of distributions. Just for the discussion, let's assume both distributions are gaussians, so I know how to parameterize them. From the first distribution I have n samples and from the second distribution I have m samples.

I know there are many statistical tests to calculate the distance of the two distributions from their samples. But in this case there's a catch: n >> m.

m is not large enough to try to reliably fit the samples to a distribution. The large difference between the quantity of samples from each distribution creates an uncertainty of the parameters of the distributions, making it harder to calculate a definitive distance. So, in order to make this more well defined, I want to calculate the smallest probable distance between the two distributions.

Comment: Why would you need to "fit" a distribution to the samples you have? You can compute the distance from the discrete measures you have

Comment: you can compute the distance from the discrete measures, but it won't have any statistical meaning to the distance. if one group of 1000 samples came from a gaussian N(0, 1), and the other group is 50 samples from a gaussian N(0, 5)- the samples will look pretty much the same. Computing the distance from the discrete measures will give me a low number with no statistical significance.  Ideally, I would like to have a test that tells me "with 99% probability, from the given samples it is guarantied that the two distributions are with distance x. Also, the complexity of the solution is O(n*m).